# What is the correct way to send ASCII through Socket on Java?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I'm trying to send some `ASCII` code, and I'm not sure about what kind of `UTF` I need or what is the correct way to send it (It starts sending numbers, normal strings, and works fine... but `ASCII` read by `.readUTF()` gives an encode `String`) Thanks in advance!

**SERVER**

```
private void sendData() throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream entityData;

    // El cliente ya se ha conectado
    OutputStream out = cliente.getOutputStream();

    /**
     * Para poder enviar tipos primitivos (incluido String) necesitamos una
     * clase de conveniencia como DataOutputStream en lugar de OutputStream
     * (que solo permite el envio de bytes)
     */
    String s = "(_̅_̅_̅_̅_̅м̅a̅я̅i̅j̅u̅a̅n̅a̅_̅_̅_̅ ()ด้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็็็";

    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(out, StandardCharsets.UTF_16);

    osw.write(s,0,s.length());
    //String butterfly = "Ƹ̵̡Ӝ̵̨̄Ʒ";
}
```

**CLIENT**

```
private void receiveData() throws IOException {

    InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();

    //data = new DataInputStream(input);

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(input, StandardCharsets.UTF_16) ;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    // wait for response
    String responseLine = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(responseLine);

    /*entityData = new ObjectInputStream(input);

    String s = entityData.readUTF();

    System.out.println(s);*/
}
```

Comment: Highly professional payload :D

Comment: "I'm trying to send some ASCII code" - no, the text you've provided is most certainly *not* ASCII. It's also pretty unclear what problem you're facing - or whether the `ObjectOutputStream` declared at the start is relevant, or why you've got commented out code in your client. Do you actually need to send a mixture of different types of data, or is it actually just going to be text? (If it's a mixture, `DataOutputStream` makes sense; otherwise, just use `OutputStreamWriter`...)

Comment: That is an interesting test string for sure.

Comment: I want to send exactly the same ASCII "String s value" but reading by UTF gives different code...

Comment: There's anyone who could resolve this one? Just what I want is to send to a client the same as you are watching on the screen, a joint made on String, I don't know what kind of data I have to use... Thanks anyway!